# Amazon Resource Name for S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have to fill in a template for my IT team to create a key using KMS in aws for S3 bucket to be used in cost and usage reports. The template asks for ARN/s for IAM user account. How to find/ mention the ARN/s for the same?

I have no clue. Pls help

Comment: What template? CloudFormation template?

Comment: NO its just excel tempalte that the IT team has for any key creation requirement. Its just that I need ARN number for it. ANy clue??

Comment: Are you using AWS console? How do you access your S3 bucket?

Comment: Is the question regarding how to structure an ARN, or rather how to find the value for said ARN? For S3, the general structure is: arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name, but in general, you can refer to: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html

Comment: The ARN of the IAM user is of the form: arn:aws:iam::${AccountId}:user/${Username}. You need to know the AWS account id and the IAM user name.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the IAM role and select the user.
You find the:
User ARN arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXX:user/XXXXXXXX
Path /
Creation time XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX